# ERROR:flutter/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41) Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: flutter

[image: Error:]

I upgraded my app version, Now, It is not running these errors are poping again and again, I tried each and every thing from the internet already, I am using flutter version 3.7.0

how to fix it because i tried pub outdated, pub upgrade and pub get or even i restarted my ide several times too